# Voice Channel Detection Erorr

Tags: discord, discord.js

When I'm Trying To Make My Discord Music Bot I Get An Error In Discord Not The Command Line Though, It Cannot Tell If I'm In A Voice Channel Or Not
Here's My Code

```
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}play`)) {
        execute(message, serverQueue);
        return;
    } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}skip`)) {
        skip(message, serverQueue);
        return;
    } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}stop`)) {
        stop(message, serverQueue);
        return;
    } else {
        message.channel.send('You need to enter a valid command!')
    }
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', error => console.error('Uncaught Promise Rejection', error));

async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
    const args = message.content.split(' ');

    const voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
    if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a voice channel to play music!');
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.bot.user);
    if (!permissions.has('CONNECT') || !permissions.has('SPEAK')) {
        return message.channel.send('I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!');
    }

    const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
    const song = {
        title: songInfo.title,
        url: songInfo.video_url,
    };

    if (!serverQueue) {
        const queueContruct = {
            textChannel: message.channel,
            voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
            connection: null,
            songs: [],
            volume: 5,
            playing: true,
        };

        queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContruct);

        queueContruct.songs.push(song);

        try {
            var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
            queueContruct.connection = connection;
            play(message.guild, queueContruct.songs[0]);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            queue.delete(message.guild.id);
            return message.channel.send(err);
        }
    } else {
        serverQueue.songs.push(song);
        console.log(serverQueue.songs);
        return message.channel.send(`${song.title} has been added to the queue!`);
    }

}

function skip(message, serverQueue) {
    if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!');
    if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send('There is no song that I could skip!');
    serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function stop(message, serverQueue) {
    if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!');
    serverQueue.songs = [];
    serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function play(guild, song) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);

    if (!song) {
        serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }

    const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.playStream(ytdl(song.url))
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log('Music ended!');
            serverQueue.songs.shift();
            play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
        })
        .on('error', error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
}
```

I Found It On This Website https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-create-a-music-bot-using-discord-js-4436f5f3f0f8

And When I Start The Code It Says I'm Not In One,
Any Type Of Feedback Would Be Greatly Appreciated!

Comment: Which version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: i'm using discord.js Version 12.2.0 In Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Try this

if (!message.member.voice.channel)
      return message.reply('you are not in a voice channel'),

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that you're using the [`GuildMember.voiceChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voiceChannel) property, which exists only in discord.js@v11. The v12 equivalent is [`GuildMember.voice.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channel), you can use it like this:

```js
// You can use this as before, since it's the same VoiceChannel element
const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel
```

Comment: But I Still Get An Error Here It Is : DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Comment: That alone doesn't mean anything, you should look at the stack to figure out where it comes from, even doing some debugging: it's possible that the errors in your code are more than one. The debugging it's up to you though, in SO you should only ask for specific problems

Comment: yeah, can you help tell me where to put the Handler Please

Comment: What handler are you referring to?

Comment: this one process.on('unhandledRejection', error => console.error('Uncaught Promise Rejection', error));

Comment: That should be in the global scope, so it seems to be in the right place